# Behat test browser does not scroll down to find element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, behat

When I run my behat test, it opens Firefox as expected. However it does not find for example a button because it doesn't scroll down in the page.

But when I quickly zoom out in the browser enough by pressing ctrl+-, then I can see that behat suddenly does scroll down and find the button that it needs to press.

I don't know what's the cause to this problem. Anyone can give a direction?

The error message:

On line:

```
And I press "Add to cart"
```

> (Element is not clickable at point (407.6000061035156,
>   15.699996948242188). Other element would receive the click: 
>   Command duration or timeout: 86 milliseconds Build info: version:
>   '2.51.0', revision: '1af067d', time: '2016-02-05 19:15:17' System
>   info: host: 'LBNL03572', ip: '10.38.188.18', os.name: 'Windows 7',
>   os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_17' Session
>   ID: 948e4f65-f1bc-492b-9c6d-07735d09b59f Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities
>   [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox,
>   handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true,
>   rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=44.0}])

***Update:***

I think it's because on top of the page there is a menu bar with position absolute/fixed on top with a height of 35px. I think that in the "normal" state, it scrolls down but the button itself is under the menu bar. So it can't click it, actually it tries to click on the menu bar div. And by accident when I zoom out the button is clickable or something.
Can I force it to scroll more or something?

***Update 2:***

I now use the function shared on https://gist.github.com/MKorostoff/c94824a467ffa53f4fa9

So before I press the button I scroll to it

```
And I scroll "edit-submit" into view
And I press "Add to cart"
```

Now it works because it scrolls down until the button appears on the bottom of the page. I think by default behat uses a page down like scroll method. So when it scrolls, step by step, the button would be on top. 
But I don't consider this a good solution. Because this implies that every time I want to press a button I first need to add that scroll to line. There should be a way to automatically scroll correctly and take in to account the fixed positioned menu bar on top.

Comment: Can we get the actual error message? The position of the button on the page is irrelevant, so there shouldn't be any need to scroll or maximise - assuming the element isn't activated by some special JS, e.g. the Visibility API.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a URL so I can see it myself?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not public just yet.

Comment: I think it's because on top of the page there is a menu bar with position absolute 0 and a height of 35px. I think that in the normal state, it scrolls down but the button itself is under the menu bar. So it can't click it. And by accident when I zoom out the button is clickable or something.

Comment: You can scroll to a particular location in the view, which should get past problem of that element being hidden, and without having to maximise. Sound plausible?

Comment: But you don't always know to which coordinates to scroll right? The text on the page can be longer or shorter then you anticipate.

Comment: But just enough to make it visible (this is hard to visualise), i.e. scroll down 200px, not to an absolute location.